# How to group the data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this when i query data from multiple table:

```html
+-------------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
| ComponentId | TxId | AccountNo |  BillNo   | RevenueCode | Amount |
+-------------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
|           1 |   27 |    080200 | 080200600 | PT3819      |   1.00 |
|           1 |   28 |    060005 | 320128254 |             |   5.00 |
|           1 |   29 |    201816 | 201830029 | 960245      |   1.00 |
|           1 |   30 |    770304 | 201999999 | 71494       |  13.00 |
|           1 |   30 |    770304 | 201999999 | 71413       |  13.00 |
+-------------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
```

My question is, how can i group the row with the same TxId even they have the same RevenueCode so that instead of the 2 rows appear, only 1 row appear. I tried using GROUP BY but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sample output would help!

Comment: what for the revenue code? ... in txid 30 you have two different revenuCode  ..

Comment: Do you have a column which could identify the order in which transactions occured such as an auto_increment id?

Comment: Do you get an error when you use group by?

Comment: share your sample output regards your data

Comment: Please share sample output

Comment: if possible i want the data to be presented like this :

|           1 |   30 |    770304 | 201999999 | 71494, 71493       |  13.00 |

Comment: You can share a more elaborate output and not just a one-liner

Answer (score 1):

If you have an auto_increment column a correlate sub query to select the min in will work

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int auto_increment primary key,ComponentId int, TxId int, AccountNo int,  BillNo int,   RevenueCode varchar(10), Amount decimal(10,2));
insert into t (ComponentId , TxId , AccountNo ,  BillNo   , RevenueCode , Amount)
values
(           1 ,   27 ,    080200 , 080200600 , 'PT3819'      ,   1.00 ),
(           1 ,   28 ,    060005 , 320128254 , null          ,   5.00 ),
(           1 ,   29 ,    201816 , 201830029 , '960245'      ,   1.00 ),
(           1 ,   30 ,    770304 , 201999999 , '71494'       ,  13.00 ),
(           1 ,   30 ,    770304 , 201999999 , '71413'       ,  13.00 );

select * from t where id = (select min(id) from t t1 where t1.TxId = t.TxId)

+----+-------------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
| id | ComponentId | TxId | AccountNo | BillNo    | RevenueCode | Amount |
+----+-------------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
|  1 |           1 |   27 |     80200 |  80200600 | PT3819      |   1.00 |
|  2 |           1 |   28 |     60005 | 320128254 | NULL        |   5.00 |
|  3 |           1 |   29 |    201816 | 201830029 | 960245      |   1.00 |
|  4 |           1 |   30 |    770304 | 201999999 | 71494       |  13.00 |
+----+-------------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you don't have an auto_increment id I would think about adding one.

You may be able to get away with a group by on txid.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(ComponentId int, TxId int, AccountNo int,  BillNo int,   RevenueCode varchar(10), Amount decimal(10,2));
insert into t (ComponentId , TxId , AccountNo ,  BillNo   , RevenueCode , Amount)
values
(           1 ,   27 ,    080200 , 080200600 , 'PT3819'      ,   1.00 ),
(           1 ,   28 ,    060005 , 320128254 , null          ,   5.00 ),
(           1 ,   29 ,    201816 , 201830029 , '960245'      ,   1.00 ),
(           1 ,   30 ,    770304 , 201999999 , '71494'       ,  13.00 ),
(           1 ,   30 ,    770304 , 201999999 , '71413'       ,  13.00 );

select * from t group by txid;

+-------------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
| ComponentId | TxId | AccountNo | BillNo    | RevenueCode | Amount |
+-------------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
|           1 |   27 |     80200 |  80200600 | PT3819      |   1.00 |
|           1 |   28 |     60005 | 320128254 | NULL        |   5.00 |
|           1 |   29 |    201816 | 201830029 | 960245      |   1.00 |
|           1 |   30 |    770304 | 201999999 | 71494       |  13.00 |
+-------------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But I would not recommend it since group by without aggregate functions are a non-standard (in sql terms) mysql 'feature'. If you get a only_full_group_by error check the manual or google the error for 'solutions'

Group concat

```
select ComponentId , TxId , AccountNo ,  BillNo   , group_concat(RevenueCode) Revcodes , Amount 
from t group by txid;

+-------------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
| ComponentId | TxId | AccountNo | BillNo    | Revcodes    | Amount |
+-------------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
|           1 |   27 |     80200 |  80200600 | PT3819      |   1.00 |
|           1 |   28 |     60005 | 320128254 | NULL        |   5.00 |
|           1 |   29 |    201816 | 201830029 | 960245      |   1.00 |
|           1 |   30 |    770304 | 201999999 | 71494,71413 |  13.00 |
+-------------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: can i get the data to be like 

|           1 |   30 |    770304 | 201999999 | 71413, 71494       |  13.00 |

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct t.ComponentId, t.TxId, t.AccountNo, t.BillNo,
STUFF((select '|' + m.RevenueCode from t m where m.TxId  = t.TxId FOR XML PATH 
('')),1,1,'') as RevenueCode ,
STUFF((select '|' + m.Amount from t m where m.TxId  = t.TxId FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') 
as Amount from t
```